# Summarising the autocorrelation of multiple time series

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation

The fluorescence signal of a molecule in multiple cells is described by multiple time series. The number of time series is in the hundreds and observations were taken every ten minutes.
Apart from other methods, I'm looking into using autocorrelation to determine the presence of oscillations. For now, I have calculated the autocorrelation per time series as well as the confidence intervals ([Hanke & Wichern](https://books.google.ch/books/about/Business_Forecasting.html?id=kY2lPwAACAAJ&redir_esc=y)).

A similar question has been raised [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31621/autocorrelation-from-multiple-time-series-samples) already. I believe, however, that this question concerns *one* time series but sampled differently multiple times. Furthermore, I think that the accepted solution is no applicable to my question for similar reasons.

Now, I'm wondering whether there is a way to summarise the autocorrelation coefficients and confidence intervals across all time series? For instance, averaging (mean?) the observations per equal time points across time series and then calculating the confidence intervals on the averaged data?
Preferably, there's a way to cite the possible solution.

It can be assumed that the observations within a time series are not independent. The observations of different time series, however, are.

**Edit:**
For the determination of the periods, I took the time difference between first and second positive ACC peaks outside the confidence interval. Is this correct?

Comment: Definitely do not average your data and then estimate something. How about you plot the distribution of all the autocorrelations?

Comment: I'm not sure that I know what you mean. When I plot the autocorrelation coefficients (ACC) I get a distribution with peaks at 0 and 1. This doesn't help determining the period and summarising the ACCs.

Comment: You are talking about an autocorrelation plot, which plots many different lags with autocorrelations, however in your question you mention autocorrelation coefficients, which are for a fixed lag, so which is it?

Comment: Isn't an autocorrelation plot collecting the ACCs for all tested lags, i.e. lags on the x-axis, ACCs on the y-axis?

Comment: Yes, but thats the plot, an AC coefficient is just one value, for one specific lag. What are you trying to report?

Comment: At the end, I'd like to show the distribution of the periods in the signal and something like an average autocorrelation across all time series (if that's possible/meaningful that is).

Comment: But are you interested in a specific lag or do you want to cram all the lags up to x into the results? If you want multiple lags, why not show the distribution of ACs separated by lags, that is instead of having only one point per lag you have a whole distribution per lag?

Comment: Ah, I see that I was not precise enough. I don't know which period to expect. Thus, I'm interested in all lags in a specific range. Plotting a distribution per lag would then be not feasible.